# Align item on flex box does not center align children CSS

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to align the parent container's children: with a flex display contentHeader but I get this result:

[image]

I would like the child (also a flexbox) to be centered with the h1 and thus all children of the parent container to be in the same Y axis.
This is the flex structure:
[image]

These are my css rules:

```
.searchDiv{

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    font-size: 16px;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    align-items: center;
}
.contentHeader{

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    gap: 10%;
    width: 100%;
    align-items: center;
    
}

.event h2{
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 34px;
}

.centralContent{
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 4%;
}
```

This is the url: https://www.goatcode.it/me/codeCeptStudio/dah/

Why, despite having set the align items center, the child container doesn't align?

Comment: Because there is a `margin-top` for every `div` inside `.contentPage` on your page.  It applies on your `.searchDiv` too.

Comment: use `.contentPage > div {margin-top: 2.5%}`   line 164 in style.css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-items  flex-end

```
    .contentHeader{

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    gap: 10%;
    width: 100%;
    align-items: flex-end;
    
}
```